# Entry file error in react native from packager

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a react-native project, which works fine on other people's machines, but I'm getting the following error. I've tried doing the following:

- Clean install of node, npm
- rerunning npm install and rnpm link

it seems like the path string is being changed to "global code@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.js", but they look fine in the config files.

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/dennisjeong/mobile-bebop/bebopRecruitMobile 

[11:15:00 AM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[11:15:00 AM] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[11:15:05 AM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[11:15:05 AM] <START> find dependencies
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Crawling File System (19327ms)
[11:15:20 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (213ms)
[11:15:20 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (153ms)
[11:15:20 AM] <START> Building Haste Map
[11:15:20 AM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (66ms)
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Building Haste Map (166ms)
[11:15:20 AM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (19867ms)
transformed 726/726 (100%)
[11:15:21 AM] <END>   find dependencies (16307ms)
[11:15:21 AM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (16406ms)
[11:15:21 AM] <START> symbolicate
[11:15:21 AM] <START> find dependencies
[11:15:21 AM] <START> find dependencies
transformed 726/726 (100%)
[11:15:22 AM] <END>   find dependencies (498ms)
NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file global code@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/dennisjeong/mobile-bebop/bebopRecruitMobile"]
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/Users/dennisjeong/mobile-bebop/bebopRecruitMobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:288:13)
    at /Users/dennisjeong/mobile-bebop/bebopRecruitMobile/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:226:30
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
[11:15:22 AM] <END>   symbolicate (511ms)
[11:15:22 AM] <START> symbolicate
[11:15:22 AM] <END>   symbolicate (341ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out that after updating to RN 0.28 my app is spitting this issue due to incompatible dependencies. This is how I solved this problem

`rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean`

Then open package.json except **react-native** change all package versions to *

Then run 

`npm update --save
npm update --save-dev`

Check package if package.json is updated with version numbers, if not verify from npmjs and update manually

Delete app from the device and try to run again