# Cannot Find entry file index.ios.js in any of the project roots ["/Users/neo/newProjects/F2"]

Tags: android, ios, react-native

## Actual Behavior

Instead of launching, I get a red screen and this error message when launching a react native projects from scratch: Cannot Find entry file index.ios.js in any of the project roots ["/Users/neo/newProjects/F2"]

## Expected behavior

Launch of a clean app starter

## What I am trying to do

I'm trying to init and run a react-native project from scratch in the android and ios simulator, but I'm getting the following error.

## What I have tried

I've tried doing the following:

#### Install via documentation

- Moving through the install steps outlined here several times:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

#### NPM Install

- Performing NPM Install from within the project folder

#### Editing .profiles ( android )

- editing the ~.profiles file, to set the android home variable.. this is what it looks like now:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" $`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools`
```

#### Npm start

Running npm start and checking activity on the port, ( was the package manager running )

#### checking the port for activity

( forget how, verified its available )

#### Code that worked for someone...

I have also tried running this code in the terminal

```
react-native bundle \
--entry-file=index.ios.js \
--platform=ios \
--dev=false \
--assets-dest=./production/ios \
--bundle-output=./production/ios/ios.jsbundle
```

After reviewing this article https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8664

And got this error message: 
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './production/ios/ios.jsbundle'

#### I noticed this suggestion

rerunning npm install and rnpm link

I tried running rnpm link, but got "no such command found"

after reading this article
[Entry file error in react native from packager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999468/entry-file-error-in-react-native-from-packager)

#### In the same article I saw this:

"Figured out that after updating to RN 0.28 my app is spitting this issue due to incompatible dependencies. This is how I solved this problem"

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
```

Then open package.json except react-native change all package versions to *

Then run
    npm update --save
    npm update --save-dev

Check package if package.json is updated with version numbers, if not verify from npmjs and update manually

Delete app from the device and try to run again

- But I cannot discern what the advisor is doing here... and the logic behind it... if it seems relevant, can someone comment on this?

## Terminal Output

I am getting this in the terminal:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling: Error
at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath 
(/Users/neo/newProjects/F2/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:272:11)
at DependencyGraph.getDependencies (/Users/neo/newProjects/F2/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/index.js:216:26)
at Resolver.getDependencies (/Users/neo/newProjects/F2/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/Resolver/index.js:106:27)
at _resolverPromise.then.resolver (/Users/neo/newProjects/F2/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/Bundler/index.js:561:62)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Bundling `index.ios.js`  0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

## Versions

Node v7.9.0
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0
Homebrew 1.2.0
Just updated xcode
OSX 10.11.6 (15G1004)

## What I notice

I notice that it seems to be looking in this file..  ["/Users/neo/newProjects/F2"] whereas in some locations on my machine the files are organized Users/Neo/...  ( capital username ) ... and I sense that has something to do with this.

also, on project build it does throw this warning... not sure what it means... 
    "react-native@0.44.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6"

Any suggestions or ideas?

## update

#### tried changing directories out of the users folder and initializing

here is what I got in the stacktrace

```
2017-05-02 09:25:21.478 xcodebuild[52491:5334564] Error saving log: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/code/F4/ios/build/Logs/Build/B9E13558-CCE5-4451-AC21-7E643189BF7B.xcactivitylog, NSLocalizedDescription=No such file or directory} | User info: {
NSFilePath = "/code/F4/ios/build/Logs/Build/B9E13558-CCE5-4451-AC21-7E643189BF7B.xcactivitylog";
NSLocalizedDescription = "No such file or directory";
```

}

```
    Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F4.app
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
    Failed to install the requested application
    An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
    Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F4.app/Info.plist
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

#### Also, tried installing expo and running from there...

Heres what the terminal shows

    `Error sourcing shell startup scripts: /Users/neo/.bash_profile: line 2: rbenv: command not found
    /Users/neo/.bash_profile: line 4: rbenv: command not found
    /Users/neo/.bash_profile: line 5: rbenv: command not found
    /Users/neo/.bash_profile: line 7: rbenv: command not found
    /Users/neo/.bash_profile: line 9: rbenv: command not found
    /bin/bash: shell_session_update: command not found
.`
Please run ``` npm install -g exp && exp path``
    10:25:22 AM
    Starting React Native packager...
    10:25:31 AM
    Scanning 656 folders for symlinks in /code/my-new-project/node_modules         (11ms)
    10:25:32 AM
    Loading dependency graph.
    10:25:32 AM
    Running packager on port 19001.
    10:25:32 AM
    10:25:37 AM
    Dependency graph loaded.
    10:25:51 AM
    Project opened! You can now use the "Send Link" or "Device" buttons to view your project.
    10:36:58 AM
    Couldn't start project on Android: could not install *smartsocket*     listener: Address already in use
    ADB server didn't ACK
    * failed to start daemon *
    error: cannot connect to daemon ```

`

Comment: "on project build it does throw this warning... not sure what it means... "react-native@0.44.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@16.0.0-alpha.6"" ignore this for now. it's not about you and won't affect anything. And I also agree it may be about your username, Neo. Have you tried initializing a project somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you!! 
If I go above the user folder is gives an access denied... with sudo I can create a new folder.  tried that. then run react-native init - 

and I get this error...
 EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/code/F4'

with sudo react-native init - it lauches a  new project... trying this now

Comment: There was a time where I swapped computers and dropped the old user profile from one machine to another.   I think I need to change ownership of all the files ..,  chown something?  sound familiar?

Comment: Oh... I think I know the problem.  prior to dragging the user profile from one machine to the other, I had to create one that was identical to link it to...  I must have simply called it Neo instead of neo... lol... I bet thats the source of the problem... anyways... testing your solution... thank you.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not that good with command line, but it should be annoying being stuck like this. Let me know the result!

Comment: If that fails, we can try installing expo, a container like that may help.

Comment: ok, its throwing out this error now... 

    Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier 
    build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F4.app/Info.plist
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

this sound like progress?

Comment: it definitely is, show me the remaining stack trace.

Comment: Expo looks amazing!! - Installing it now but that looks like its going to save time!

Comment: Yes it is indeed :)

Comment: ok, added to the body of the post above at the end

Comment: so does expo work? It seems OK, the only problem you seem to have is adb, not related to installation of expo.

Comment: Any idea what this sentence means?      ADB server didn't ACK?  Whats adb?  Ack?

Comment: So expo does work, although the one guy helping me seems resistant to embrace it, because he has an existing rhythm.   On the up side, expo seems to accelerate so many things and does get the app running... on the down side, it does require that I have anyone helping me use the same platform if they are going to contribute to the code build.   That sound right to you?

Comment: Why not? That guy can test the app using their own device in no time. Afterall its also a great tool for collaboration. Lets just focus convincing that guy :)