# What tools do you use to accelerate your react-native development

Tags: react-native

I started with react native development and it is slow, and my client expects a an app delivered to the appstore within 10 weeks.

My initial challenges getting set up are outlined here:
[Cannot Find entry file index.ios.js in any of the project roots ["/Users/neo/newProjects/F2"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732788/cannot-find-entry-file-index-ios-js-in-any-of-the-project-roots-users-neo-new)

In the process of searching for solutions I found 2:

https://expo.io/
Seems to radically accelerate development

Genymotion
Simulator - seems faster then android studio and xcode

What other tools do you use to accelerate your react-native development?

Answer (score 4):

I personally think that using `expo` is one of the easiest ways to make native apps quickly and without needing deep knowledge of things like `XCode`. Since they only use one `main.js`, you don't have to have duplicate code between `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js`, which really speeds up development for cross platform apps.

The main downside to using `expo` is that you can't use custom modules that use native code.

That being said if your app is relatively simple most of the cool things you would want to implement work out of the box :). You can always check out the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v16.0.0/index.html) as well, to see if what you want is supported. You can also pop into the `expo` [slack](https://slack.expo.io/) channel or [forums](https://forums.expo.io/) and ask anything you might want to know more about.

Answer (score 0):

- I'd just like to reiterate that as a developer starting out with React Native i'd say Expo should be your GoTo tool for development.
- In terms of tools i'd say having a good text editor/IDE is essential. 
  For me Visual Studio Code fits the bill.
  It has tonnes of extensions that can speed up your work.
- Also checkout this set of github repo of amazing react native libraries:
  [Awesome React Native Github](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start with react-native init than using expo , it pays you in long run. though working with Xcode and android studio is bit tricky in the beginning it very crucial u understand how react native interact with native code.